# How to return the value of fetch on sections.php

Tags: php

DBOperations.php

```
 public function studentSection($uname) {
        $this->sections = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT students.id, students.lastname, sections.name AS section_name, years.name AS year_level, academic_years.start, academic_years.end FROM students INNER JOIN section_student ON students.id = section_student.student_id INNER JOIN sections ON section_student.section_id = sections.id INNER JOIN years ON sections.year_id = years.id INNER JOIN academic_years ON sections.academic_year_id = academic_years.id WHERE students.s_id = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $uname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            return $this->sections[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 
                'section' => $row['section_name'],
                'year_level' => $row['year_level'],
                'school_year' => $row['start']."-".$row['end']);
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

section.php

```
if($db->studentLogin($uname)){
            $sections = $db->studentSection($uname);
            $response['error'] = false; 

        $response['id'] = $sections['id'];
        $response['lastname'] = $sections['lastname'];
        $response['section'] = $sections['section'];
        $response['year_level'] = $sections['year_level'];
        $response['school_year'] = $sections['school_year'];

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "No Data";          
    }
```

There's an error when it return the value `Illegal string offset`. 
It doesn't display all the data. 
the output is `{"error":false,"id":"[","lastname":"[","section":"[","year_level":"[","school_year":"["}`

When I tried to `return` the `$this->sections` inside the while it display all the data that equals to `1` then i change the `return` below into `echo json_encode($this->sections)` it works. but It only display one row. it should display all the data row that equals to `1`.

Comment: Value should be __returned__ from function, and not echoed in it. There's a `return` statement, read a manual about it.

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query if it returns valid data?

Comment: @OmolewaStephen yes sir, i already run

Comment: @u_mulder I already tried the `return $row;` but still it doesn't display all `s_id` that equalts to `1`

Comment: Because `s_id` is __not__ in `SELECT` fields.

Comment: I'll update my error sir, cause I can't post a new one

Comment: I already update the post @u_mulder

Comment: Why do you call `json_encode` within that function and try to access the returned data as if was an array? The returned value is a string

Comment: when I change the `return json_encode($this->sections);` into `echo` it display all the data array. how to returned value string? @NicoHaase

Comment: `return $this->sections`, isn't it?

Comment: Just don't return a string, don't echo it, just return the generated array. After all, is there any need of keeping it in a class property like `$this->sections`?

Comment: @NicoHaase it only display the 1st row. it doesn't display the other row that equals to `1`. it should display the other row that equals to `1`

Comment: it only display the 1st row. it doesn't display the other row that equals to `1`. it should display the other row that equals to `1` @u_mulder

Comment: @NicoHaase I'll update the post

Comment: Well, it only returns the first row if you run the `return` within the loop. Do that after all rows have been aggregated, and (I don't want to be too rude, but honest) have a thorough look into a simple PHP tutorial

Comment: Because you take `$sections['id']` from __array__. Please learn basic debugging techniques, at least with `print_r`, `var_dump`. Understand what is array, what is multidimensional array, how to access it's keys. Otherwise you will do useless changes in your code.

Comment: @NicoHaase ok thanks. I'll try too look

Comment: where I should put the foreach ? @NicoHaase

Comment: Don't change the `foreach`, but use `return` after that loop has finished

Comment: @NicoHaase ok sir. I'll try it tomorrow. cause I already go home and I'm just using phone.